# Use empty list in ServiceStack.Redis

Tags: c#, list, redis, servicestack.redis, empty-list

In ServiceStack.Redis, a list with a key is present in redis, only if the list contains at least a single entry.
If all the entries are removed from that particular list, then executing the command:

```
KEYS *
```

shows that the corresponding list key is removed from redis.
Is it possible to have a list in redis without any value?  Once a list is created, values are added / even after all values are removed from that list, the corresponding key should be available when KEYS * code is executed

How to create such a list / set